# Android dialog showing empty ListView

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-arrayadapter

I want to show a list of cars in an Android Dialog and it keeps showing nothing. 
Note: purchasedCars.getCars() is not empty
Here is the code:

```
  findViewById(R.id.buy).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyCarActivity.this);
            View dialogView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_list,null);
            builder.setView(dialogView);

            ListView listView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, purchasedCars.getCars()));

            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check your inflated layout its seems to look like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and can you test if you change `purchasedCars.getCars()`

to - > `new String[]{"test","app"}`

for example

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"test","app"}));
```

OR

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
                list.add("test");
                list.add("app");


listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
```

check if thats work if yes .. you need to take a look for what `purchasedCars.getCars()` return .